# Export selective tables with names from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Our production database has around 2000 tables and all of them are listed in a table (Project) with another column marking them as 1 for test and 0 for prod. I need to export the tables marked as 0 to our test environment.

So how is it possible in `SQL Server` or `SSIS` to export some of the tables whose names will be result of a query?

Table names will be result of this query:

```
select tableName from [Project] where test = 0
```

Comment: What do you expect by 'Export'?, Do you want to export table with data to a new database?, or want just to get table structure to a new DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task to take a part of database structure and data is not trivial unless your tables do not indexes, relations and so on. The task that relatively easier is to drop what you do not need. But again if your tables have any relations you need to do dropping in correct order. So the task could be completed in the following steps:

1. Add one more column to table `Project`, say DropOrder. Fill it manually with correct order taking in mind your current constraints.
2. Make backup your test database and restore it at production location.
3. Run script to drop test tables. This script can use simple dynamic sql `DROP` statement.

Of course, this is general idea without knowing much details. For example, may be better to swap step 3 and 2 or have more complex functionality for dropping script.

Comment: Happy to hear this. BTW I think that this solution has more to deal with - for example, you need to shrink tables and logs to optimize production database, etc.